# Explain the differences between these methods of sending e-mail from Excel?

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

My Excel macro needs to start a new e-mail, with the current workbook as an attachment. (All of the users have Outlook.) The user can modify anything in the e-mail, then click "Send".

I've found two different examples online to do this, but one involves much more code than the other. The simpler version seems to work, but I wonder if there's a reason for the complexity of the other.

The short version:

```
Dim strRecipient, strSubject As String, booReturnReceipt As Boolean

strRecipient ="dummyEmail@example.com"
strSubject = "Enter Subject Here"
booReturnReceipt = True

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show Arg1:=strRecipient, _ 
         Arg2:=strSubject, Arg3:=booReturnReceipt
```

The long version:

```
Sub Mail_ActiveSheet()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016

Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim Destwb As Workbook
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
With Destwb
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2016
        Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
        Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        Case 52:
            If .HasVBProject Then
                FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
            Else
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            End If
        Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
        Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
        End Select
    End If
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With Destwb
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "dummyEmail@example.com"
        .Subject = "Enter Subject Here"
        .Body = "Hi there"
        .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Close savechanges:=False
End With


Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Is there really an advantage to using CreateObject("Outlook.Application")?
Is it really useful to change the file type when attaching it?

Thanks.

EDIT: Based on the first two answers, it must not be clear that the Short Version functions the same way as the Long Version: rather than just **send** an e-mail, it opens the Compose E-mail window of Outlook (which all of the users have), with the active workbook already attached. The user can edit, add or change recipients, etc. before pressing "Send".

Answer (score 1):

> Is it really useful to change the file type when attaching it?

Not that I am aware of unless you are attaching an **Exe** file.

> Is there really an advantage to using CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For me, **Yes**. It is easy to use (*be it late or early binding*). It is part of MS Office (*depending on the package you take*). Most of the people have it.

Your long version can be reduced by approx 50-60 %. Here is a example (**Untested**) using **Late Binding**.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Dim Destwb As Workbook

    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .to = "dummyEmail@example.com"
        .Subject = "Enter Subject Here"
        .Body = "Hi there"
        .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
        .Display ' .Send
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

You can cut down few more lines if that really matters :)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Dim Destwb As Workbook

    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False: .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .to = "dummyEmail@example.com"
        .Subject = "Enter Subject Here"
        .Body = "Hi there"
        .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
        .Display ' .Send
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing: Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True: .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### From the first example

- `Dim strRecipient, strSubject As String, booReturnReceipt As Boolean`

  This is not being declared properly. Right now strRecipient is being declared as a variant. The correct method would be `Dim strRecipient as String, strSubject as String, ...`

---

### From the second example

- `With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = False
      .EnableEvents = False
  End With`

  These lines speed up the procedure.
- `If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
      'You use Excel 97-2003
  Else`

  These lines mean that this procedure is prepared for handling any version of Excel. This code is more portable.

---

```
If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
    'You use Excel 97-2003
    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
Else
    'You use Excel 2007-2016
    Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
    Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
    Case 52:
        If .HasVBProject Then
            FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
        Else
            FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        End If
    Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
    Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
    End Select
End If
```

This code is useful if you open a non-Excel file in Excel - for example, if you use Excel to do text-to-columns on a delimited or fixed width text file. By attaching as `.xlsb` for non-Excel files, you preserve the Excel features that you added by manipulating the file in Excel.

> Is there really an advantage to using CreateObject("Outlook.Application")?

Paraphrasing what Sidd already said, there can be. I know that when you use the base `Send Mail` prompt for Gmail, you get a more stripped down application to work with. I am not sure if the same is true for Outlook, but if it is, this would allow you to use the full-featured Outlook for your mail. For example, I am not sure if `Send Mail` prompts include signatures.

```
With OutMail
    .to = "dummyEmail@example.com"
    .Subject = "Enter Subject Here"
    .Body = "Hi there"
    .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
    .Display
End With
```

Finally, this method allows you features the `Send Mail` prompt doesn't - editting the body text of the e-mail, etc.

Sorry for the inconsistent formatting, the StackExchange editor was a bit finicky for what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: Actually, you don't "attach by hand". The xlDialogSendMail variable automatically attaches the workbook as soon as the e-mail page opens.

Comment: Thank you very much @ShawnV.Wilson! I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered a significant difference. The Short Version does not allow you to automatically put anything in the message body (which is mainly the point of a form letter).

For some messages -- for instance, a report that the recipient expects every week -- a longish Subject line would suffice.